# Can I create an array of Condition variables in Java?

Tags: java, monitor

I am trying to implement a Monitor using condition variables. My problem is that I want to create many Condition variables.

```
private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
final Condition[] self;
```

How do I initialize the Condition-type `self` array?

Comment: You'd initialize it like any array. How large it is and what instances you use to fill it are dependent on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: And you may want to consider an `ArrayList` or similar structure that has a simple `add()` or `put()` and `get()`  methods to add/remove/access elements as needed. Much better than realizing you need to resize an array ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating a list of conditions.

Code Example :

```
List<Condition> conditions = new ArrayList<Condition>();
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
conditions.add(lock.newCondition());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Slaw and Stephen C for correcting my horrible first answer.

Initialize your `final` array as if it wasn't final. [Slaw's not exact words->] The final keyword means that you can't reassign array to a new array. You can still `modify` the elements IN the array.

For example, you can initialize your array "self" as `new Condition[1];`, then do `self[0] = new Condition()` and then do `System.out.println(self[0]);`.

Comment: Better :) Now I'd just like to point out that one should not create an instance of `Condition`—which is an interface, by the way—via `new Condition()`. Instead, they are created from an instance of `Lock`, via [`Lock.newCondition()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#newCondition()).

Comment: I did not go this route because as @Slaw mentioned you cannot initialized a condition variable using `new Condition[1]`.

Comment: @dreamerboy That's not what I said. I said creating a condition via `new Condition()` is wrong. Using `new Condition[1]` creates the _array_. To fill it you'd do something like `self[0] = lock.newCondition()`.